# How to find index for time, lat, lon for particular variable point in xarray

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing, netcdf, python-xarray

I have the following netcdf file opened as an xarray dataset, which contains monthly values of precipitation. Here is what the dataset (ds3) looks like:

[image]

I would like to isolate values above a certain threshold and return the indices for each value. For example:

```
outliers = ds3.where(ds3.tp > 0.08, drop=True)

for x in outliers.tp:
    print(x)
```

[image]

When I loop through the outliers, it gives me the information for each 'tp' value, but I need the associated indices.
For example, taking the one tp value of 0.08361223 (in the image above) I would like to return the time_index (index for 1981-03-01), lat_index (index for 8.25) and lon_index (index for 38.25).
I am new to netcdf files and python and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like :

```
ds3['tp'].where(ds3['tp'] > 0.08, drop=True).to_dataframe().dropna().reset_index()
```

It would give a pandas DataFrame with the values you want with its associated coordinates. In order to have the integer indexes associated, you may write :

```
df = ds3['tp'].where(ds3['tp'] > 0.08, drop=True).to_dataframe().dropna().reset_index()
for c in ds3.indexes:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda v: list(ds3[c].values).index(v))
```

It's not very elegant, but works.

Comment: this is what I was needing. Got to the point of converting to a dataframe but needed the reset_index() and the association. Thank you.